# How to handle multiple buttons with actions

Tags: buttons

I have multiple buttons in the header of my application. I wonder how to improve the UX.

[image]

Buttons explanation:

- RECALCULATE - if some critical fields are changed, this button should be activated
- CANCEL OR REJECT - this is very straightforward (cancel/reject the submission)
- CHECK QUOTATION - after the user is ready all data are correct, user can trigger this button and it will perform some business checks and eventually generates the Quotation file (if all checks pass)
- DOWNLOAD QUOTATION FILE - this generates sort of preview of the quotation file (draft) whenever user wants

I'm looking for suggestions how to improve the UX. Also links to articles are appreciated.

EDIT:
I was thinking.. what do you think about this guys?

[image]

Comment: Have you already tried "any" UX design?

Comment: sorry I do not understand .. what does "any" stand for? I am very new to UX design ..

Comment: You have five buttons and all five have a different layout, so I'm asking if you've tried anything or at least seen a similar situation to start from

Comment: we didn't want to make them all of the same size because they would be too huge.. so we thought making them a little smaller might help (which obviously didn't work much) .. I was wondering it putting them under one ACTION_dropdown sort of thing would help .. but then users might not see all the options they can do .. like for example, we can hide the recalculate and show only when needed, but still.. what would be the right design/layout/positioning?

Comment: If this is really the design then there is a lot to improve, too much to cover in an answer. I suggest to look for inspiration, see some tutorials, read UX books, but most of all to try things out.

Comment: :( ...any tips?

Comment: Take a look to [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/51294/115107)

Comment: thx a lot !!!!!

Comment: added some example.. hoping for your comments guys :)

Comment: What happens when clicking on "Actions" and what happens when clicking on the arrow?

Comment: same thing - the menu get's expanded - the arrow only visually indicates there is something in it